# SQL Server 2008 - Only find inactive records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query that shows only inactive orders. An inactive order is defined as an order having no active order items.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM    Orders INNER JOIN
        OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID INNER JOIN
        Products ON OrderItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID INNER JOIN
        ProductSubCategories ON Products.ProductSubCategoryID = ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID INNER JOIN
        ProductCategories ON ProductSubCategories.ProductCategoryID = ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID
WHERE   (Orders.CustomerID = @CustomerID) AND (OrderItems.OrderItemStatusID = 2) AND (ProductSubCategories.ProductCategoryID = 1)
GROUP BY    Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
```

OrderItems.OrderItemStatusID = 2 signifies the order item is inactive. OrderItems.OrderItemStatusID = 1 means the order item is active.

The problem is that the query lists not only all the inactive orders but those with both an inactive and active order item.

For example

Order 123 has both an inactive and active order item. It should not show up in the query result but it does.

Order 234 has all inactive order items. It shows up correctly.

How do I exclude order 123?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM    Orders INNER JOIN
        OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID INNER JOIN
        Products ON OrderItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID INNER JOIN
        ProductSubCategories ON Products.ProductSubCategoryID = ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID INNER JOIN
        ProductCategories ON ProductSubCategories.ProductCategoryID = ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID
WHERE   (Orders.CustomerID = @CustomerID) AND (ProductSubCategories.ProductCategoryID = 1)
GROUP BY    Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
HAVING MIN(OrderItems.OrderItemStatusID) = 2
```

Comment: @Mike, This is not the most efficient query but since it has @CustomerID in it, it shouldn't matter, assuming a single customer doesn't have millions of orders and there is an index on CustomerID column.

Answer (score 2):

Write a subquery that finds all orders with active items, then use that to identify all orders that are not within that dataset.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderID NOT IN (SELECT <query finding all orders with active items>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM    Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderID NOT IN
(select distinct o.OrderId 
 from Orders o
     left join OrderItems oi on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
 where oi.OrderItemStatus != 2)
```